# Exact match of String contents in Php

Tags: php

I would like the following code to only replace strings which match exactly, not partial matches. For instance; replace "Navy" with "Blue" not "Navy Ship" with "Blue Ship"

```
<?php
function replaceWords($value) {
    //here are predefined values
    $predefined = array(
        array(`enter code here`
            'search'=>'Navy, Dark Blue, Blackcurrant, Blue/White, Navy Blue',
            'replaceWith'=>'Blue'
        ),
        array(
            'search'=>'Rose, Dark Red, Pink, Maroon, Burgundy',
            'replaceWith'=>'Red'
        )
    );
    //search and replace
    foreach ($predefined as $item) {
        $search = array_map('trim', explode(',', $item['search']));
        $value = str_ireplace($search, $item['replaceWith'], $value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Comment: then make your str_ireplace conditional. `if ($color == $item['replacewith']) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, would the code look like $value = str_ireplace if ($color == $item['replaceWith'], $value); ?

Comment: You need to define an exclusion list for word combinations that you want to ignore such as "Navy Ship".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There are hundreds of combinations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$value = preg_replace("/\b(".$search.")\b/", $item['replaceWith'],$value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace exact strings if they are present in an array, simply check if it is present in the array and return the result if it is.

```
foreach ($predefined as $item) {
    if (in_array($value, $search)) {
        return $item['replaceWith'];
    }
}
```

However, if you want to ignore case, replace all elements in the predefined values to lowercase and use `strtolower($value)` rather than just `$value`.

Answer (score 0):

array(`enter code here`
            'search'=>'Navy Ship',
            'replaceWith'=>'Navy Ship'
        ),

it will stop navy ship to being replaced.